# accessing dynamic input values in ember #each block in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I'm having issues accessing input values within my component.  I'm trying to dynamically create value bindings in my templates and accessing in the conponent.js file using this.controller.get("pst"+id) however the result is underfined.  Using Ember 2.2

```
{{#each post in |pst idx|}}
    {{input value=(concat 'pst' idx)}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Ember version? Try `{{#each post as |pst idx|}}`

Comment: it seems to be an issue with creating the variable that the value is binded to.  The concat helper function builds a string, but when I try this.get.controller("..") on dynamically created string it does not return the value of the input box (and returns undefined)

Comment: I believe what you need is the `get` helper, possibly in conjunction with concat: `(get this (concat "pst" idx))`.

Comment: I tried that with no dice.  I also tried just this.get('idx'+i);

Answer (score 0):

Well, [it works as expected](https://ember-twiddle.com/c9c163b4e80e51c22a46c528a86e72c0?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C), but why would you want to do this?

Please explain what you want to archive and then we can help better.

And to be clear, a value generated with the `get` helper is immutable.

Why not do something like `{{input value=pst}}`?
If this is not an option probably you should build your array in JS and use that then in handlebars!

Answer (score 0):

Define a computed property that wraps your 'post' variable in your component.js file. Iterate over that wrapper. I think this is a powerful way of generating dynamic values.

Your template:

```
{{#each postWrappers as postWrapper}}
    {{input value=postWrapper.value}}
{{/each}}
```

Your component.js:

```
postWrappers : Ember.computed('post', function() { 
   //your concat code
});
```